# MVC- Not found page http://local.../Articles/1

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can you help me? I used contoller HomeConrtoller.cs for view, edit and delete articles. All work, but When I go to the next page I get error don't found http://local.../Articles/1
public ActionResult Articles(int? page)

> ```
>  {  
>     var viewData = mybaseRepository.FindAllArticles();  
>     const int pageSize = 10;  
>     var paginatedArticle = new PaginatedList<Article>(viewData, page ?? 0 ,   pageSize);  
>    ViewData["Page"] = paginatedArticle.PageIndex;  
>    return View(paginatedArticle);  
>  }     
> In Global.asax.cs  
>  routes.MapRoute(  
>   "Articles",  
>   "Articles/{page}",  
>   new { controller = "Home", action = "Aticles", page = (int?)null }  
>   );
> ```
>
> paging in Articles.aspx
>        
>         <% if (Model.HasPreviousPage) {  %>
>           <%= Html.RouteLink("предыдущая <<<",
>             "Articles",
>               new {page = (Model.PageIndex - 1) })%>
>            <% } %>

```
    <% if (Model.HasNextPage) { %>    
        <%= Html.RouteLink(">>> следующая",    
         "Articles",     
          new {page = (Model.PageIndex + 1) })%>   
   <% } %>        
<div>
```

Comment: Do you have only one route in your Global.asax? Or you have also Default routing too?
routes.MapRoute(  
  "Default",  
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}",  
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  
  );

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "Articls" in the URL but "Articles" when defining the route. Would that be it?

Comment: Another typo is `action = "Aticles"`

Comment: William's right. still mapping action's Aticles. new { controller = "Home", action = "Aticles", page = (int?)null }